# SQL: Unique constraint when column is a certain value

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
   dt     AS DATE NOT NULL,
   type   AS TEXT NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT unique_dt_type UNIQUE(dt,type) -- check constraint(?)
)
```

Having a brain-dud when trying to think of the right syntax to create a unique constraint when only a certain condition exists.

Given, `type` can have values `A-F`, there can only be one `A` per date, but there can be multiple `B-F`. Example of good table:

```
2010-01-02 | 'A'  -- only one
2010-01-02 | 'B'  -- can have multiple
2010-01-02 | 'B'
2010-01-02 | 'B'
2010-01-02 | 'C'  -- can have multiple
2013-01-02 | 'A'  -- only one
2010-01-02 | 'B'  -- can have multiple
2010-01-02 | 'B'
2013-01-02 | 'F'  -- can have multiple
2013-01-02 | 'F'
```

Tried reading check/unique syntax but there weren't any examples.  `CHECK` came close but only limited it to a range and wasn't used in conjunction with a `UNIQUE` scenario.  Also tried searching, but my search skills are either not up to par, or there aren't any similar questions.

Comment: You can easely do it using a trigger!

Comment: @Houari: that sounds promising, do you have a quick example?  I did find some results when I searched for `sql conditional unique`, but no success (they were dated)

Comment: I might have found a solution in the question stated here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/987099/183181 , if `where` is allowed during index creation

Comment: Yep, look up "partial indexes" in the Postgres manual. You can do `Create Unique Index ... Where ...`, and it will be enforced like a constraint. (I'm on a phone, else I'd expand that into an answer)

Comment: @IMSoP: It looks like RThomas hijacked your answer - thanks guys

Comment: Ha, we all converged on the same answer within a few seconds of each other.  It wasn't there when I was posting.

Comment: @RThomas not me, i was looking for a trigger solution :p

Comment: Bonus points: [Followup Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889375/sql-typecast-in-a-unique-index)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

PostgreSQL can address your needs via it's "Partial Index" feature.  In practice this is accomplished by adding a where clause to the create index statement.

Sample:

```
CREATE INDEX my_partial_ix ON my_sample_table (my_sample_field)
WHERE (my_sample_field = 'rows to index');
```

Take a look here:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html

Pay particular attention to the section `Example 11-3. Setting up a Partial Unique Index`.  It gives an example that lines up well with your stated objective.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_partial_ix ON my_sample_table (my_sample_field)
WHERE NOT (my_sample_field = 'duplicates ok');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "CheckConstraint"()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$declare
already_exists boolean; 
begin

if new.foo_type='A' then
select count(*) >0  from foo where foo_type='A' and dt=new.dt INTO already_exists;
if already_exists then 
raise exception 'date % already have an A', new.dt;
end if;
end if;

return new;
end;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Comment: Way too complicated. This won't scale and using a partial index is much faster and more robust.

Comment: Plus, the index automatically serves to speed up matching queries. Only tiny drawback: the index needs some disk space.