# SQL: Typecast in a Unique Index

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    dt AS DATE,
    ts AS TIMESTAMP
);
```

What's the proper way to create a unique constraint where the date value of `ts` occurs once per `dt`; example:

```
dt         | ts
2010-01-02 | 2010-01-02 17:19:08
2010-01-02 | 2011-11-11 01:01:01
2010-01-02 | 2011-11-11 17:19:08 -- would error on insert (already a 2011-11-11)
```

Attempt:

1. Invalid syntax, but what I'm trying to achieve:

   ```
   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_tsdate_per_dt ON foo(dt,ts::date);
   ```
2. Incomplete attempt - possibly a subquery?

   ```
   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_tsdate_per_dt ON foo(dt) WHERE ts::date -- ?
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the function form of the `::date` cast:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_tsdate_per_dt ON foo(dt, date(ts));
```

Then you'll get results like this:

```
=> insert into foo (dt, ts) values ('2010-01-02', '2010-01-02 17:19:08');
=> insert into foo (dt, ts) values ('2010-01-02', '2011-11-11 01:01:01');
=> insert into foo (dt, ts) values ('2010-01-02', '2011-11-11 17:19:08');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_tsdate_per_dt"
DETAIL:  Key (dt, date(ts))=(2010-01-02, 2011-11-11) already exists.
```

Comment: My next test was to try `cast()`, but `date()` will work -- thx