# MySQL unique combination of two values only when "enabled" feature is present

Tags: mysql, data-structures, constraints

A *table* has two columns *folio* and *company* and a third column *enabled*. The combination of the first two columns must be unique only when *enabled* is set with true or "truthy" value.

#### How to implement constraints to guarantee the rules described above are always enforced?

Possible:

```
folio | company | enabled
    2         B   false
    2         B   false
    2         B   true
```

Not possible:

```
folio | company | enabled
    2         B   false
    2         B   true
    2         B   true
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insted of false use `NULL`,mysql treats `NULL` as a different value in an `UNIQUE` constraint and leave true as it is.
Then put an unique key on all 3 columns.

[Test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37a7c2/1)

Just repeat the last insert and it will not let you.

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL doesn't support such types of constraints.

You should use stored procudures for inserting data instead, so you can do some checking and validation.

see ref:[Unique Constraint with conditions in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987099/unique-constraint-with-conditions-in-mysql?lq=1)