# Conditional Uniqueness Constraint Ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have following model level uniqueness constraint and need to move same to MySQL level. What is the SQL statement to do same.

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :uniqness_of_title

  def uniqness_of_title
      blog = Blog.where("title=? and lock_version<>-1", self.title).last
      self.errors.add :base, "Title already exists." if blog
  end
end
```

and It should allow to make entry into 'blogs' table even if title already existed with record having lock_version=-1.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE blogs ADD CONSTRAINT uc_title UNIQUE (title)
```

Comment: I need to validate lock_version column too. If blog title  existed with lock_version=-1. It should allow to make entry.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with mysql constraints (opinion that is backed up by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987099/unique-constraint-with-conditions-in-mysql). Personnally, I would leave the business logic conditions such as this one in the model.

Comment: @born4new Uniqueness can *only* be guaranteed by the database. If you have 3 Rails application servers, you might perform 3 model-level checks simultaneously, have none of them find an existing with that title, and all of them create a new one. How best to do that with MySQL is another question.